# PHP installs httpd instead of FPM from build

Tags: centos, php

I am on a CentOS VPS, and whenever I install php from build, it installs httpd server instead of php-fpm. In short, I can start php using `service start php-fpm` as I would normally do if I was to install php from webtatic or remi repos. Here is how I am building php after installing the `*-devel` components.

```
$ wget http://ch1.php.net/get/php-5.6.0.tar.bz2/from/this/mirror
$ tar jxf php-5.6.0.tar.bz2
$ cd php-5.6.0/
$ ./configure --with-mysql --enable-mbstring --enable-exif --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd --enable-cli --with-gd  --enable-session --enable-dom --enable-phpdbg --enable-fpm --enable-ctype --with-vpx-dir --with-jpeg-dir --with-png-dir --with-xpm-dir --with-freetype-dir
```

Comment: Are you getting anything from the configure output which indicates that the `fpm` version is not going to be built for some reason? Is the issue here that the `fpm` version isn't getting built? Is the issue that there is no service entry created by that name? Is the issue that no service entry is being created at all? Are you actually running `make` and probably `make install` after running that `./configure` line?

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes. Sorry, I have done `make install` after `./configure` which took about 15 minutes. I didn't get any issue. All went smoothly. What I don't understand is how `httpd` got installed and not fpm. Yes, the issue is `fpm` isn't getting built.

Comment: No `php-fpm` binary is created in the source directory?

Comment: @EtanReisner In short, there is nothing named `fpm`. It's just not there

Comment: Could you follow this tutorial? Maybe you are missing a lib or something. If thats a problem, please paste somewhere the output log of the ./configure and make install commands. http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-use-multiple-php-versions-php-fpm-and-fastcgi-with-ispconfig-3-centos-6.3

Comment: @Gonza Thank you, but I am not trying to group install. Do you have a tutorial without that?

Comment: @Contax No... but maybe if you take a look at the ./configure and make commands you will find something about a missing library. Take a look at the output logs or paste somewhere. (BTW here is another nice reference http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/php.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd a successful installation with the following commands:

```
wget http://ch1.php.net/get/php-5.6.0.tar.bz2/from/this/mirror
tar jxf php-5.6.0.tar.bz2
cd php-5.6.0/
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php  --enable-fpm --with-mcrypt \
--enable-mbstring --disable-pdo --with-curl --disable-debug  --disable-rpath \
--enable-inline-optimization --with-bz2  --with-zlib --enable-sockets \
--enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --enable-pcntl --enable-mbregex \
--with-mhash --enable-zip --with-pcre-regex --with-mysql --with-mysqli \
--with-gd --with-jpeg-dir

make all install
```

If any library is missing, please consider run the following commands on demand:

```
yum -y install gcc automake autoconf libtool make
yum -y install libmcrypt-devel mhash-devel libxslt-devel \
libjpeg libjpeg-devel libpng libpng-devel freetype freetype-devel libxml2 libxml2-devel \
zlib zlib-devel glibc glibc-devel glib2 glib2-devel bzip2 bzip2-devel \
ncurses ncurses-devel curl curl-devel e2fsprogs e2fsprogs-devel \
krb5 krb5-devel libidn libidn-devel openssl openssl-devel
```

I'm not sure, if removing `--enable-cli` really helps, but you can try.

And by the way, for production environment, I'd recommend you using `nginx` instead of `httpd`, which has very impressive performance. The configuration migration to `nginx` is also very easy, if you do not have a lot of `.htaccess` files.

Comment: Yes. I am trying to install php-fpm with nginx. Are you installing other software that has nothing to do with php/nginx? because, there are lots of them, some I don't have any idea of at all.

Comment: @Contax I've installed PHP 5.2 with nginx and memcache using source packages. First of all, you might uninstall the whole httpd stack and then deactivate remi repos.

Comment: Actually, I am on a fresh vps. I am not using remi/webtatic repos.  Like I said though, have you added anything to the list that isn't about php? like e2fsprogs? what does it do?

Comment: No, I've setup a clean vps (minimal installed debian 6 server edition) and the install PHP with all related dependencies from scratch. I think you'd better add more details into your question, so that we can help to focus the real problem.

Answer (score 2):

try to use this configure-line

```
./configure --disable-all --with-mysql --enable-mbstring --enable-exif --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd --enable-cli --with-gd  --enable-session --enable-dom --enable-phpdbg --enable-fpm --enable-ctype --with-vpx-dir --with-jpeg-dir --with-png-dir --with-xpm-dir --with-freetype-dir
```

and also need to see output error.

Comment: Please explain why should OP use this

Answer (score 1):

Note that you have to change `--enable-cli` with `--enable-fpm` which is optional anyway and proceed by make

```
$ wget http://ch1.php.net/get/php-5.6.0.tar.bz2/from/this/mirror
$ tar jxf php-5.6.0.tar.bz2
$ cd php-5.6.0/
$ ./configure --with-mysql --enable-mbstring --enable-exif --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd --enable-fpm --with-gd  --enable-session --enable-dom --enable-phpdbg --enable-fpm --enable-ctype --with-vpx-dir --with-jpeg-dir --with-png-dir --with-xpm-dir --with-freetype-dir
$ make 
$ sudo make install
```

Run a test

```
/usr/local/bin/php -v
# Outputs: 
# PHP 5.x.x (cli) (built: xxx)
# Copyright (c) 1997-20124 The PHP Group
# Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologiesnginx version: nginx/1.2.1
```

Comment: Why should I change `--enable-cli` with `--enable-fpm` it seems that is where the problem is